# strange encounter when passing checkbox to server side

Tags: node.js, pug

I am encountering a strange problem when passing some arguments from my jade's template form to my server.

Here is the context, the form is used to search movies, each movie can be caracterized by an array of genres. In my form there is a list of checkbox like this :

```
div Genre :
    br
    label(for="genre") Drama
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Drama")
    label(for="genre") Crime
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Crime")
    label(for="genre") Thriller
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Thriller")
    label(for="genre") Action
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Action")
    label(for="genre") Adventure
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Adventure")
    label(for="genre") Sci-Fi
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Sci-Fi")
    label(for="genre") Biography
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Biography")
    label(for="genre") Comedy
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Comedy")
    label(for="genre") Music
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Music")
    label(for="genre") Romance
    input(type="checkbox", name="genre", value="Romance")
```

The problem is on the server side, when more than one checkbox is checked everythings works fine. For exemple if I check "Drama" and "Crime", I can see req.body.genre[0] contains "Drama" and req.body.genre[1] contains "Crime" and **req.body.genre.length equals 2**.

The problem is if I only check one genre, for exemple "Drama". **req.body.genre.length equals 5** and everything is stored as :

- req.body.genre[0] = "D";
- req.body.genre[1] = "r";
- req.body.genre[2] = "a";
- req.body.genre[3] = "m";
- req.body.genre[4] = "a";

The problem appears when I check only one genre no matter which one. I have no idea why !

I am atempting to build a query dynamicaly :

```
// If a genre was selected
if (req.body.genre.length > 0)
{
    // If more than 1 genre was selected
    if (req.body.genre.length > 1)
    {
        query["genres"] = {};
        query["genres"]["$in"] = req.body.genre;
    }
    else
    {
        query["genres"] = req.body.genre;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input(type="checkbox", name="genre[]", value="Drama")
```

In other words, instead of using `genre` as name, use `genre[]` (for all `INPUT` elements).

This tells the `bodyParser` middleware that it should always parse results into an array (instead of returning a string when only one checkbox is selected, and an array if multiple checkboxes are selected, which is what's happening in your situation).

You can still access the results as `req.body.genre` on the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works perfectly with your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because when only 1 is checked, you aren't getting an array sent, but a string.  That strings length, "Drama" for example, is 5.  So then you end up dividing up all the letters.